# How to change the texture of pudding?

Tags: pie, ice-cream, pudding

I made this recipe today that involves making instant pudding with chocolate ice cream instead of milk.  It was supposed to come out as a super chocolaty mouse but it tasted a little grainy, like not all the pudding got incorprated. I rarely use box pudding but I was thinking this could be a quick dessert to yank out if needed.  Anyway, I was wondering what the best way to knock out the graininess was. Should I add some milk or just use more ice cream?

The original recipe was from serious eats : http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/08/cakespy-chocolate-ice-cream-pie-recipe.html

Comment: One quick question for an Englishman.  What is pudding (in the US-sense you are using it)?  We use the word a lot, but it is another (more common) word for dessert, or specifically a hot dessert, particularly one cooked in a basin.

Comment: @Orbling, *pudding* in US parlance is something akin to eggless custard: a milk-based dessert thickened with a starch of some type. In practice, this most often means getting the box of instant pudding & pie filling from the pantry and combining it with cold milk according to the recipe on the box; but you can also buy cook & serve pudding (milk is still the only ingredient you need to add, but you cook it for a short while); or you can make your own using milk, sugar, flavoring, and flour or cornstarch.

Comment: @Marti: Cheers for that.  Trying to think if we have anything similar, there are various "puddings" of that type, but usually more than just a starch, usually some sort of solid lumps, be it tapioca, semolina, or most commonly short-grain rice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem could be the refreezing of the ice cream.  You know when you take out ice cream, eat at it for 5 or 10 minutes and then put it back in the freezer...and then the next time you take it out, some of the ice cream is a little icy and bit grainy?

I'm not sure you can solve this if you use the same recipe.  Instead, I would recommend using the highest fat chocolate milk you can find instead of using melted chocolate ice cream.

I really doubt the pudding didn't get dissolved completely.  If that really was the case, you could heat the mixture before you put it in the pie crust.

Comment: The pie is never refreezing, it's merely going back into the fridge for about two hours.

Comment: Ah right.  Perhaps heating the mixture in a pot first before putting it in the pie crust.

Comment: I found adding a splash of cream and mixing for a little longer fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!