# how to fix pudding that got extra sweet?

Tags: flavor, sugar, dairy, pudding

i have made the chocolate pudding and accidentally added loads of sugar..now it is too sweet n too sticky..what can i do with it except throwing it out?

Comment: If you post the ingredients used, we may be able to suggest something more specific.  For example I could see turning it into a chocolate frosting of some kind, but it would be hard to know how without knowing what's in the original mix.  Also if you can, please see the comments on this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4936 - as this is an international site, please clarify what definition of pudding you use :) Probably the cold "US" version, but want to be sure.

Comment: @stephennmcdonald: I am definitely never going to get used to the US definition of that word!

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the ingredients necessary to make more?  You could make a second batch, without adding sugar, and combine them.

Answer (score 2):

I once ran into the same problem. I ended up making frozen pudding pops out of them. Boy were they a hit.

I just put the pudding in several ice cube trays and a few wax coated paper cups.

Pop them into the freezer.

Insert plastic spoons or popsicle sticks when it gets frozen enough to hold the spoon or stick. .

Serve with a smile, you are about to achieve 'Hero' status.

Comment: This can work because cold suppresses flavors, including sweetness. But if there's way more sugar than needed, then (a) the flavor won't be suppressed enough, and (b) chances are the pudding won't freeze very well - sugar inhibits freezing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's stiff, it could be used to top or fill a sponge cake. Icing is sweet by design. If it isn't stiff adding more icing sugar should stiffen it enough to set.